# How To Hide WordPress widget from homepage only ? But Need To Show on Post and Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to hide a WordPress widget from homepage but need to show on post and page. I am using this:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) && !(is_home) : ?>
```

But this is showing an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Features\sidebar-main.php on line 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is_home is a function - so you need a couple of parentheses at the end of it  - like so: `is_home()`. You also appear to be missing a bracket at the end of the line; your if-statement should read like this:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) && !is_home() )
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a closing bracket, try this:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) && !(is_home)) : ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using the incorrect conditions. You have to use

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) && !is_home() ){}
```

You can also use **[`Widget Options`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-options/)** to hide WordPress widgets without editing the code and available on the repository for free. The options will be visible on each widgets. Feel free to check.

[image]